# Windows FTP maximum connections?

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I have some code which uploads some files to multiple places. This code starts a shell cmd window for each upload and they all start at the same time using C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe in Windows 7.

The code used to open the uploads over some time, but an improvement in the code (to save the total time the job takes) now sees the uploads start at the same time and since then, I have noticed the actual transfer commands hanging sometimes as if they were waiting for other connections to finish their transfers first. This causes some of the connections to time out from the server end.

So my question: does windows FTP have any kind of maximum connection or transfer settings that can be altered?

Comment: Any limits would be hardware not software.

Comment: I would have have though that too...

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your code then